# Scala JUnit @BeforeClass not executing

Tags: scala, junit

I am trying to run Scala Junit tests with a `@BeforeClass` method. When I run this test class, the `setup()` method is never executed. What am I doing wrong here? I am using JUnit 4.12 and Scala 2.10.5. The rest of the test executes as expected.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.junit.BeforeClass
import org.junit.Test
import junit.framework.TestCase

object PerformanceTest extends TestCase {

  var sc: SparkContext = _;

  @BeforeClass
  def setup(): Unit = {
    if (sc == null) {
        sc = new SparkContext("local", "ANTLR Expression Test")
    }
  }
}

class PerformanceTest extends TestCase {

  @Test
  def testWeightedAverage(): Unit = {
    val csvRDD = PerformanceTest.sc.textFile("src/main/resources/MOCK_DATA.csv")
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting, it looks like removing `extends TestCase` from both the `object` and `class` makes it to work.  Hopefully you're happy to use the JUnit 4 approach of using annotations rather than `TestCase` inheritance.

Comment: JUnit unses the JUnit3 runner because of the `extends TestCase` and this runner does not support annotations. It runs the test case `testWeightedAverage` not because of the `@Test` annotation but because its name starts with test.

Comment: @StefanBirkner Excellent answer. JUnit3's `@BeforeClass` is through extending `TestSuite`, right? Would extending `object` in Scala with this class have done the trick too I wonder...